# MAMP and PHP on Terminal

Tags: php, terminal, mamp

So I have installed MAMP and I am using PHP, however I also used Terminal with PHP as well. Now for some reason Terminal is not working with PHP anymore, for example:

Terminal / PHP command not found

[image: Terminal / PHP command not found]

So basically I can not work with anything at the moment. I have also simplified .bashrc and .bash_profile.

Terminal and PHP not found

[image: Terminal and PHP not found]

Thanks. mac-machine

Comment: You're using `zsh`, not `bash`. Have you made sure `zsh` reads `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Correct is there a way to default this back to .bash.

Comment: iirc `zsh` has a `.zshrc` file you could use to add to the path or make `zsh` read ` those two files or uninstall `zsh` if you don't want to use it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is working with PHP command line is not found with ZSH, it  gets a message: **zsh: command not found: php**.

So working with older BASH instead of ZSH it works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

1. `cd ~` && `nano .zshrc`
2. Add the path of php in `.zshrc` like:

   export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin:$PATH
3. Then run `source .zshrc` and run `php -v` to confirm path setup